# Is there way to call Dreamweaver Mediator from C# TBB in Tridion?

Tags: dwt, c#

I have Dreamweaver code in one text block as string. What i need is will it be possible to call Dreamweaver mediator from C# TBB and pass the string in text block in Tridion

Comment: This sounds rather bizarre! Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a component in tridion which has text field and it contians the "Dreamweaver Code". Then i have one TBB with which i have created CT and that CT is used to render this component. The TBB need to fetch the Dreamweaver Code in the text field of the component and by calling Dreamweaver mediator and execute the string fetched.

Comment: @AnandNatarajan: Why are you trying to place "Dreamweaver Code" in a text field? It doesn't looks like a right way. It would be better if you can elaborate on question with more details such as what "Dreamweaver Code" you placed

Comment: The reason you are finding this hard to achieve is that it doesn't fit the model. You shouldn't try to make your Components into Component Templates.

Comment: I'd bet money that between us we could figure out a way to do this. Tridion  is flexible enough. However, if I did figure it out, I don't think I'd tell you the answer. This is just wrong on so many levels! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The Template expression language (sometimes referred to as Dreamweaver code) is designed to get content from Components in your layout.

There is the concept of a "[double lookup](http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/04/dreamweaver-double-lookup.html)" by using the `@@` signs on the outside and the `${` on the inside, which you could use to parse values from a field from your Component, but I don't know of a way to call the Mediator from a C# TBB itself.

Answer (score 1):

TBBs are self-contained by nature, and talk to each other by pushing or getting package variables in the TBB pipeline (the list of TBBs in Template Builder for a Compound Template).

We usually don't reuse HTML snippets from one DWT in many various Compound Templates.  It's a bit too granular and modular to do it like this.

Your C# TBB would push the processed data into a package variable (list of components, for example, or a processed field) and the the purpose of the DWT template is to simply output the package variable or Component field (it has access to all the Component fields) with HTML.  DWT templates are often the last or almost last TBB in a Compound Template, since their output is finished HTML.

Another way to think of a DWT template is a MS Word template where you put placeholder variables in a document and then connect it to a DB to render 100s of documents only pulling the variables (like name or address) from the DB and the hard coded text (HTML in DWT terms) remains in the doc.

I hope this is a little more clear now...